# Proving $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I want to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group. I have proved it myself but, as an unexperienced student, I'd like to check with you if my reasoning is correct. I have already proved that the operations:
$$ [a]+[b]:= [a+b] \quad \mbox{and} \quad [a][b]:=[ab]$$
are well-defined, and this proof is correct since I followed my algebra book. Now, to prove $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group, this is what I've done:

(1) $([a]+[b])+[c] = [a+b]+[c] = [a+b+c] = [a]+[b+c] = [a]+([b]+[c])$, proving associativity of the sum;

(2) The identity element on this group is $[0]$ since $[a]+[0] = [a+0] = [a] = [0+a] = [0]+[a]$;

(3) If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $[-a]$ is the inverse element of $[a]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ so that $[a]+[-a] = [a+(-a)] = [0]$.

I think this reasoning is okay, but I wonder if when taking $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and its equivalence class $[a]\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ I must first state that this $[a]$ is equivalent to one of these sets $[0],[1],...,[n-1]$ and then prove the result for this element instead of $[a]$ itself, but I think I don't need to do this because I proved the sum is well-defined so it does not depend on the choices of representatives. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: This would prove that $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ is a ring, which is stronger than a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

However, for (1), I would write this:

$$\begin{align}
([a]+[b])+[c] &= [a+b]+[c] \\
&=\color{blue}{[(a+b)+c]}\\
&=\color{blue}{[a+(b+c)]}\\
&= [a]+[b+c] \\
&= [a]+([b]+[c]).
\end{align}$$

It is not necessary to state that $[a]\in\{[0],[1],\dots,[n-1]\}$ for each, or any, $a\in\Bbb Z$.

Also, you did not use $[a][b]:=[ab]$. Are you sure you mean *"group"* and not *"ring"*?

Comment: Thank so much for your answer! The two points you raised crossed my mind while I was posting the question too. I didn't make use of the product, but I let it there because the theorem in my algebra book proves both operations are well-defined. The expressions you wrote in blue are basically the associativity of the sum in $\mathbb{Z}$, and I omitted for simplicity but I agree with you that it is better to write it down! Again, thank you so much!!